# Not getting sounds for Notifications or Messages in my Audio app when music is playing | AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have an Audio app using AVAudioPlayer on iOS. Whenever music is playing my app and a new notification or a message comes, my player continues playing and there is no notification sound for the message.
I want that it should work in similar way default music app in iOS works, whenever a new message or notification comes music sound ducks for a while and notification sound is played and after that music starts playing normally again.

I read that setting kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers to  true should fix it as it allows mixing of sounds. I tried that as well, but it doesn't work and this also allows my app to play music along with other apps which I don't want.

All I want is whenever a message or notification comes when my app is playing music, I should get a notification sound and my app then continues playing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of try I figured it out, I had set **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord** property which was causing the above error I mentioned. removing that fixed the issue